# Minimum number of comparisons sufficient to rank any set of $n$ objects?

Tags: order-theory

Say you're given a set of objects, and you don't know the value of any of the objects, but, given a pair of two objects you are always told which one is bigger.

For a set $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$, what is the minimum number of comparisons that will suffice to put all of its elements in ascending order of size: i.e. of the form $$\{y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_n\}$$ where $y_i\lt y_{i+1}$ for all $i$?

Obviously this is easy to determine for small $n$ (by trial and error), but as $n$ increases, I'm not sure which comparisons are redundant.

Comment: This is $n\log(n)$ asymptotically - well studied. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm.

Comment: There are a total of $n!$ permutations, hence you need at least $\log_2 n!\sim n\log_2 n$ comparisons.

Comment: @EthanBolker How should I turn that into an integer? Obviously $n \log (n)$ is not always a whole number.

Comment: @RobArthan What I mean is: what's the max number of comparisons needed to be able to list all elements of the set in order of size.

Comment: The formulae that you guys have given me are inconsistent with the fact that, for $n=3$, the max number of comparisons needed is 3. And I'm not sure what to do with a number that's not an integer.

Comment: As of Aug 2011, the exact value of minimum number of comparision is not known for $n = 16$, see [OEIS A036604](https://oeis.org/A036604).

Comment: You can only turn the $n\log{n}$ approximation into the right exact integer by solving the unsolved problem @achillehui points to. I think he should post his comment as an answer.

Comment: How is $\lceil\log_2 3!\rceil =3\le C(3)=3$ inconsistent?

Comment: Do the close-vote-happy retards have Down's Syndrome or something? You can't misinterpret what I'm asking: how many comparisons do you need to be able to rank the elements of the set (in order of size)?